# Fourier serie of $e^x$ for $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$ using complex exponential expansion of $cos(nx)$

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

*I know this question has already been asked but I have not found something useful for the way I was looking to calculate this serie (using complex exponentials expansion of $cos(nx)$).*

> I want to find the Fourier serie of $f(x) = e^x$ for $x \in [-\pi, \pi] $

The coefficient $a_0$ is pretty easy to find :
\begin{align*}
 a_0     & = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^x dx \\
   & = \frac{1}{\pi}sinh(\pi)
\end{align*}

Next, the coefficient $a_n$, that's were I struggle. I'm trying to integrate by expressing $cos(nx)$ in term of complex exponentials :
\begin{align*}
 a_n & = \frac{1}{\pi}\underbrace{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^x cos(nx)dx}_{ = \textbf{I}} \\ \\
 I & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^x\frac{e^{inx} + e^{-inx}}{2} \\
  & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{x(1 + in)} + e^{x(1 - in)}}{2} \\
  & = \frac{1}{2(1+in)}(e^{\pi(1+in)} - e^{-\pi(1+in)}) + \frac{1}{2(1-in)}(e^{\pi(1-in)} - e^{-\pi(1-in)}) \\
  & = \frac{1}{2(1+in)}(e^{\pi}e^{in\pi} - e^{-\pi}e^{-in\pi}) + \frac{1}{2(1-in)}(e^{\pi}e^{-in\pi} - e^{-\pi}e^{in\pi}) \\
  & = \frac{1}{2(1+in)}(e^{\pi}(cos(n\pi)+isin(n\pi)) - e^{-\pi}(cos(n\pi)-isin(n\pi))) + \\ & \frac{1}{2(1-in)}(e^{\pi}(cos(n\pi) - isin(n\pi)) - e^{-\pi}(cos(n\pi)+isin(n\pi))) 
\end{align*}

I am stuck at this last line, I don't know how to go further.
I've been spending a few hours on this, there's definitely something I am missing.

Thanks.

EDIT : Here's the answer.

\begin{align*}
 a_n & = \frac{1}{\pi}\underbrace{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^x cos(nx)dx}_{ = \textbf{I}} \\ \\
 I & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^x\frac{e^{inx} + e^{-inx}}{2} \\
  & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{x(1 + in)} + e^{x(1 - in)}}{2} \\
  & = \frac{1}{2(1+in)}(e^{\pi(1+in)} - e^{-\pi(1+in)}) + \frac{1}{2(1-in)}(e^{\pi(1-in)} - e^{-\pi(1-in)}) \\
  & = \frac{1}{2(1+in)}(e^{\pi}e^{in\pi} - e^{-\pi}e^{-in\pi}) + \frac{1}{2(1-in)}(e^{\pi}e^{-in\pi} - e^{-\pi}e^{in\pi}) \\
  & = \frac{1}{2(1+in)}(e^{\pi}(cos(n\pi)+isin(n\pi)) - e^{-\pi}(cos(n\pi)-isin(n\pi))) + \\ & \frac{1}{2(1-in)}(e^{\pi}(cos(n\pi) - isin(n\pi)) - e^{-\pi}(cos(n\pi)+isin(n\pi))) \\
  & = \frac{1}{2(1+in)}(e^{\pi}cos(n\pi) - e^{-\pi}cos(n\pi)) + \frac{1}{2(1-in)}(e^{\pi}cos(n\pi) - e^{-\pi}cos(n\pi)) \\
  & = \frac{1}{2(1+in)}(cos(n\pi)(e^{\pi} - e^{-\pi}) + \frac{1}{2(1-in)}(cos(n\pi)(e^{\pi} - e^{-\pi})) \\
  & = \frac{1}{(1+in)}cos(n\pi)sinh(\pi) + \frac{1}{(1-in)}cos(n\pi)sinh(\pi) \\
  & = cos(n\pi)sinh(\pi)(\frac{1}{1+in} + \frac{1}{1-in}) \\
  & = cos(n\pi)sinh(\pi)(\frac{1-in}{1^2 - (in)^2} + \frac{1+in}{1^2 - (in)^2}) \\
  & = cos(n\pi)sinh(\pi)(\frac{2}{1 + n^2}) \\
 a_n & = \frac{2cos(n\pi) sinh(\pi)}{\pi(n^2+1)} \\
  & = \frac{2(-1)^n sinh(\pi)}{\pi(n^2+1)}
\end{align*}

Comment: For all integers $n$ we have $\cos n\pi=(-1)^n$ and $\sin n\pi=0$.

Comment: For sure ! Thanks.